# Excel VBA: Can't past the right values after changing one line of code

Tags: excel, vba

Would anyone explain why the following code is not working properly?
I change one line of vba code from

`copyrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Referred to testing").Range("A1")"`

to

`**"copyrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy sht2.Range("A1")"**`

when I checked the values pasted in sheet2, it only shows values in the first row, all the other values disappeared. Your help is appreciated :)
Following is the complete code:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim lrow As Integer
Dim copyrange As Range
Dim filterRange As Range
ActiveSheet.Name = "All Candidates"

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Candidates")

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Referred to testing"
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Referred to testing")

LastColumn = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
Set copyrange = sht.Range("D1:E" & lrow)
Set filterRange = sht.Range("A1:K" & lrow)

    filterRange.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="Referred to Testing"
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
   ActiveSheet.Name = "Referred to testing"
   copyrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy sht2.Range("A1")


sht2.Range("$A$1:$B$1045033").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: I should have removed these two lines on my original posting ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
   ActiveSheet.Name = "Referred to testing"

Comment: Maybe look and see what `lrow` is, I see it is not qualified, but I think it is counting the correct sheet rows.

Comment: Davesexcel - You are right on the spot! lrow shows "1" because I didn't specify which worksheet it should look at.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct line of codes for anyone interested:

```
Sub Macro1()
  Dim lrow As Integer
  Dim copyrange As Range
  Dim filterRange As Range
  ActiveSheet.Name = "All Candidates"
  Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All Candidates")

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
  ActiveSheet.Name = "Referred to testing"
  Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Referred to testing")

  LastColumn = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
  lrow = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

  Set filterRange = sht.Range("A1:K" & lrow)
    filterRange.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="Referred to Testing"
  Set copyrange = sht.Range("D1:E" & lrow)
  copyrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy sht2.Range("A1")


  sht2.Range("$A$1:$B$1045033").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
  End Sub
```